# Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError Internet Explorer

Tags: webpack, axios, babeljs, vuex, babel-polyfill

I am using Vuejs, vuex, webpack, babel-polyfill, and axios.

This error is only appearing in Internet Explorer on our production server. It works on all other browsers and on local host. I am not sure why this is happening.

I have tried to look for this issue on the vuex and axios forums but there is no luck.

I appreciate the help.

Here is the Message from the console of IE11.

Thank you!

```
Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }

Unhandled promise rejection SyntaxError
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      ABORT_ERR: 20,
      code: 12,
      constructor: { },
      DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
      DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
      HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
      INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
      INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
      INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
      INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
      INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
      INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
      INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
      message: "SyntaxError",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
      NETWORK_ERR: 19,
      NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
      NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
      NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
      NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
      PARSE_ERR: 81,
      QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
      SECURITY_ERR: 18,
      SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
      SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
      TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
      TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17,
      URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21,
      VALIDATION_ERR: 16,
      WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

This error appears when a promise you created was rejected and there was no explicit `.catch` for it. The only thing I can suggest you is to check all your code and verify that all promises have `.catch` 'es at some point.

Also, there is an event listener that can help you to figure out a reason why that promise was rejected, and where exactly it happened in the code:

```js
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function (event) {
  console.warn("WARNING: Unhandled promise rejection. Reason: " + event.reason, event);
});
```

Links:

- http://2ality.com/2016/04/unhandled-rejections.html
- https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/promise-rejection-events/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection

Comment: The unhandledrejection doesn't seem to work in IE: https://caniuse.com/#search=onunhandledrejection

Comment: @edt Good catch. One workaround I see is to disable native promises in IE11 and let babel always polyfill it. This will add support for `unhandledrejection`. In this case you need to use a bit different event listener. Check a link below
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/424#issuecomment-181928614